# How do I get Apache to reliably serve a large number of ports?

Tags: web-services, apache, wsgi

I have a dedicated server using Apache to listen to nine non standard ports (8xxx) which are supplying API services over SSL. Ports 80 and 443 are used to serve static content and an 'overwatch' service that indicates the status of the other services.

After a few days, the services start to fail because it appears that Apache is directing the service requests to the overwatch service rather than to the intended service. Restarting Apache fixes this issue until it happens again.

The services are implemented using wsgi.

There is a legacy pyramid API service configured as follows:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=ubuntu group=ubuntu threads=4 \
   python-path=/home/ubuntu/ev_mis/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /mis /home/ubuntu/ev_mis/mis.wsgi

<Directory /home/ubuntu/ev_mis>
  WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The other eight API services use Django and are configured like this:

```
# Built automatically on Wed Sep 25 13:59:51 2013
Listen 8325
<VirtualHost _default_:8325>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/services/h/rb/mis/mis_site/mis_site
    Alias /media /usr/local/services/h/rb/mis/mis_site/mis_site/media
    Alias /static /usr/local/services/h/rb/mis/mis_site/mis_site/assets

    <Directory /usr/local/services/h/rb/mis/mis_site/mis_site>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mis_site.settings.h
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/orb_services/h/rb/mis/mis_site/mis_site/mis_site/wsgi.py
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.crt
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally there is the overwatch service configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www
Alias /static /var/www/static
<Directory /var/www/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /thumbnails /var/www/thumbnails
<Directory /var/www/thumbnails>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/overwatch/overwatch/wsgi.py

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is an example wsgi.py file:

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from sys import path
from os import environ

SITE_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
path.append(SITE_ROOT)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
def application(req_environ, start_response):
    environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = req_environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                                                        environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                                                                    None))
    return get_wsgi_application()(req_environ, start_response)
```

For example: https://example.com/ yields the overwatch status table and https://example.com:8123/data/ yields service data on one of the services.

Analysis reveals that apache has mis-directed the call to the overwatch service. For example https://example.com:8123/data/ now yields page not found the debug trace reveals that it has been served by the overwatch wsgi service.

Once this happens, it happens consistently until I restart the apache service. Then everything is fine for a few days until it happens again. Apache does not report any configuration issues and starts/restarts fine.

Currently the server is only experiencing very light test traffic but it is scheduled to go live soon and I have no idea how to address this issue... short of perhaps biting the bullet and delaying launch while I reconfigure the whole thing to use nginx/gunicorn instead of apache which feels like a cop out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments.

- You should not set DocumentRoot to a directory above where your project code is. If you were to inadvertently comment out the WSGIScriptAlias, all your project code, including the settings file with database passwords could be downloaded by someone.
- You can't use 'SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mis_site.settings.h' in Apache to specify where the Django settings module is. It needs to be set in the wsgi.py file.
- Why aren't you using daemon mode of mod_wsgi for your Django sites as well? You would be running multiple instances in sub interpreters of the one process and if you aren't configuring Django correctly, that could result in requests being handled by the wrong application. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

---

UPDATE 1

Instead of using:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
def application(req_environ, start_response):
    environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = req_environ.get(
            "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE". environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", None))
    return get_wsgi_application()(req_environ, start_response)
```

You should be using:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
_application = get_wsgi_application()

def application(req_environ, start_response):
    environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = req_environ.get(
            "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", None))
    return _application(req_environ, start_response)
```

You are calling get_wsgi_application() on every request, which is a bad idea. It causes a new instance of the WSGI handler to be created on each request, which is not necessary. Doing so will also screw up the operation of monitoring tools such as New Relic.

Comment: Thanks Graham, the wsgi.py picks up the environment variable (each of the services shares the wsgi.py file but has its own apache config so this works fine). I'm looking into the daemon mode and related question now. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: SetEnv does not set a process wide environment variable. Do you mean you are using a WSGI middleware to pull it from the WSGI environ dictionary and then updating os.environ yourself? Add to you question the parts of the wsgi.py which show what you are doing.

Comment: I've added the wsgi above fyi. Your blog link gave me all of the information I needed to not only fix the problem but to also improve the configuration significantly. Thanks for the help!